# Apollo GraphQL resolves the field before calling `willResolveField`. How and where is the field 'resolve' actually happening?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to build a custom Apollo extension to capture some performance metrics (duration of execution) of resolvers and logging them to an APM tool. From the [Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/), Github issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2074) and an [example](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/8914b135df9840051fe81cc9224b444cfc5b61ab/packages/apollo-server-core/src/logging.ts) published by Apollo, I found that the method `willResolveField` when overridden, receives `GraphQLResolveInfo` (which in turn has the parent type `parentType` and field name `fieldName`). If one can notice, the fields are already resolved when this method is called by the Apollo server. Does someone know where this field resolution actually takes place before sending it to `willResolveField`?

On the other note, unless my understanding is wrong - the name `willResolveField` seems to be quite misleading. Can someone kindly shed some light on this?

Sample code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
class GraphQLAPMExtension implements GraphQLExtension<TContext> {
 requestDidStart(options:{ request, operationName, ... }) {
  // perform APM specifics to log the request and other info
  return (...errors) => {
    if(errors.length) {
     // some more custom APM stuff!
    }
  }
 }

 willResolveField(source, args, context: TContext, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) {
  // info contains parentType and fieldName
  // and it seems to be that fields are already resolved and passed to this function
 }

}
```

Comment: `willResolveField` is called before the field's custom resolver as you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/d5015f4ea00cadb2a74b09956344e6f65c084629/packages/graphql-extensions/src/index.ts#L209). It's not clear from your question why you think the field is already resolved when `willResolveField` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an extension for tracing requests that's built into ApolloServer. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-tracing/src/index.ts). It sounds like you could just fork that.

Answer (score 1):

After some amount of digging into the `graphql` package. It is looking like the function `resolveFieldValueOrError` does the resolution. It can be found under the `./execution` section. Looks like I will have to fork the graphQl project and make the modifications that I wish.

Another, more practical direction, was to trace the Apollo server creation's tracing parameter. After some quick digging, found that it is using the `apollo-engine-reporting` package.

Comment: Unless there is a middle ground that someone knows?